# Cannot find 'gflags/gflags.h' while building library OSX

Tags: c++, macos, cmake, glog, gflags

I'm trying to build the library which included `'gflags/gflags.h'` and am having trouble getting it to find.

I installed gflags and glog with homebrew.

CMake output says:

```
-- Found installed version of gflags: /usr/local/lib/cmake/gflags
-- Detected gflags version: 2.2.2
-- Found Gflags: /usr/local/include
-- Found Glog: /usr/local/include
```

While running `"cmake"` everything is okay there is no error. But when I run `"make install"` it cannot build and it says `"fatal error: 'gflags/gflags.h' file not found"`

How can I build the library which requires gflags in OsX?

Comment: try to see inside of Cmake file if Gflags path is set manually?

Comment: In Cmake file there is only 
`find_package(Gflags REQUIRED)`
`find_package(Glog REQUIRED)`

Comment: Could you provide the CmakeList somehow? My guess is that you are not linking the gflags directory for your executable.

Comment: Please provide your CMake code, including the code showing how you use the Gflags variables after the calls to `find_package()`. Without seeing the code you are using, we can only **guess** what the problem might be...

Comment: @ThomasCaissard @squareskittles Thank you guys It was problem in `include_directories`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

First, find your package

```
find_package(Gflags REQUIRED)
find_package(Glog REQUIRED)
```

And then assign these library's header files to your executable include path

```
include_directories(${GLOG_INCLUDE_DIRS} ${GFLAGS_INCLUDE_DIRS})
```

Make sure that these variables are set properly

```
message(STATUS "GFLAGS include path: ${GFLAGS_INCLUDE_DIRS}")
```

Comment: gflag and glog provide Modern CMake Targets `gflags::gflags` et `glog::glog` -> stop using deprecated *_INCLUDE_DIRS. Thx